# ios9 : Application Transport Security issue for "http://"

Tags: ios9

I am using NSURLSession for the url which has "http", but when i tried to run this, it gave a error "Application Transport security has blocked a clear text http (http://) resource load since it is insecure".

Please help me where i am doing wrong here.

Comment: there are lot of similar que. have u tried SO?

Comment: yes, i did. I have added NSAppTransportSecurity in plist and made NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is YES.